# Issue with Pandas "or" condition on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to remove rows based on the condition on two of my columns.

```
indexFZeroAmount = df[(df['F'] == 0.)].index
print indexFZeroAmount
```

the length of this array is 4468.

```
indexTZeroAmount = df[(df['T'] == 0.)].index
print indexTZeroAmount
```

the length of this array is 4172.

```
indexZeroAmount = df[((df['T'] == 0.) | (df['F'] == 0.))].index
print indexZeroAmount
```

the length of this array is 4172. Why??

this is my output:

```
Int64Index([    173,     232,    1097,    2129,    2610,    3372,    3384,    3431,    3707,    3740,
            ...
            1490233, 1490278, 1490407, 1490427, 1492461, 1492467, 1492677, 1494529, 1494724, 1494888], dtype='int64', length=4468)
Int64Index([    173,     232,    1097,    2129,    2610,    3384,    3431,    3707,    4314,    4323,
            ...
            1490130, 1490232, 1490233, 1490278, 1490427, 1492461, 1492467, 1492677, 1494529, 1494888], dtype='int64', length=4172)
Int64Index([    173,     232,    1097,    2129,    2610,    3384,    3431,    3707,    4314,    4323,
            ...
            1490130, 1490232, 1490233, 1490278, 1490427, 1492461, 1492467, 1492677, 1494529, 1494888], dtype='int64', length=4172)
```

It seems the "or" condition is not working correctly.

**Edit** 
With smaller dataset, it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'count':[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3],'x':[1,2,3,-1,-2,-3]})
print df[((df['x'] == 3)|(df['count'] == 1))].index
print df[df['count'] == 1].index
print df[df['x'] == 3].index
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb thing to suggest, but are you sure you are not looking for the `&` operator? Or to put this another, please explain why you think that having an array of length 4172 is a problem.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @WoodyPride Because `|` should return _at least_ the maximum number of either condition.

Comment: What you are suggesting, should not happen. It's either a bug or user error. We have no way of knowing without a reproducible example. As @MSeifert has already asked for.

Comment: @WoodyPride `max(4468, 4172) == 4468`. So it's not "at least the maximum".

Comment: Yep, I was being blind

Comment: @MSeifert,  the data size is around 3 TB.  I tried to reproduce it with smaller dataset but I was not able to catch the issue.

Comment: What a pity. It sounded like a really interesting problem :(